# how to make UILabel autosize text in storyboard (or interface builder), NOT programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

Every time I click-and-drag a UILabel to storyboard, and then add text to Text field, the text is cut off, so I then have to click-and-drag the UILabel to stretch it big enough so that the text appears.

I can't figure out how to make the UILabel automatically get big enough to fit the text.

This would save time while designing new views.

Comment: You asked: "How do I scale text to my view in IB."  Three people explained the opposite - how to size views to fit the text, and including the negative, they received 32 votes and a correct answer acknowledgement.  Apple has a source sample for using a CALayer to vectorize text (can't find it just now).  I used that as the basis for an IBDesignable view, so I can drop it in, set the text in IB, use constraints to externally define the size, and view the results in IB.  I can try to dig it up if you still need it.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

On any element in Interface Builder you can select the element and hit...

Editor > Size to Fit Content (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>)

This will do a "sizeToFit" on the selected element. Labels will fit their text size, image view will resize to the image size, etc...

Comment: I selected a UILable, why **Size to Fit Content ** is unavailable?

Comment: @Geaka just hit CMD =

Comment: I was wondering why Size to Fit content was greyed out for me... turned out that my UIButton was already sized perfectly to the content. If I resized the frame manually, I could later use Size to Fit.

Comment: Guys, in my XCode (v7.2.1), whenever I drag a Label to the Superview, the option "Size to fit content" under Editor Menu doesn't show enabled. So, to solve this (magically) I just go to the "Size inspector" menu icon and hit on "Explicit" checkbox in "Preferred Width".. and then hit again to enable automatic option. This seens like a XCode bug. I didn't have any constraint assigned to the view.

Comment: Note that if you are selecting the item from the overview list on the left, you have to double-click it to focus the designer pane before you can hit `Cmd`-`=`. Terrible. But thank goodness for this tip.

Comment: @Fogmeister If the option in the menu is unavailable, CMD = won't either work.

Comment: FWIW, I found the Size to Fit is disabled when the label is inside a Stack View

Answer (score 39):

In Xcode 6.1, I had to set Content Compression Resistance Priority to a higher value, likely because I have other constraints that were conflicting, or causing the sizeToFit option to be disabled.

[image: Content Compression Resistance Priority]
**Before:**
[image: Before]
**After:**
[image: After]

Comment: Only working solution on iOS 9. If you also have height constraint don't forget to set the height <= than the value

Answer (score 1):

For the text label:

Set *Lines* to 0

Set *Height* to *Greater than or equal to 30 (or other value)*

Now the *height* will be adjusted based on the lines number.

Answer (score -3):

Starting with iOS 6, there's a new API, available in Interface Builder as well called 'Auto Layout'. You can specify some contraints and UIKit will resize / move your views based on those contraints. If you don't want to use Autolayout you can use the `autoresizeMask` property of UIViews (which is settable in Interface Builder as well).

Check out the [Autolayout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)!

To resize the views in Interface Builder as you build them, see the reply from @Fogmeister

Comment: Link is broken.